# how to click on a javascript button with htmlunit?

Tags: java, javascript

Hi I have the following function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="clientscript/vbulletin_md5.js?v=387"></script>
<form action="login.php?do=login" method="post" onsubmit="md5hash(vb_login_password, vb_login_md5password, vb_login_md5password_utf, 0)">
<input type="hidden" name="s" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="login" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="vb_login_password" />    
<input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password" />
<input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password_utf" />

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" border="0">
<tr>
```

Unfortunately the function has no id or name etc. How is it possible to click on the Javascript button and get back the result? Thanks for all your answers in advance.

Comment: I think this is a java question actually, since he's asking about htmlunit.

Comment: The code is written in java not Javascript. in other words a program that has been written in Java clicks on a button that invokes a javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

Use as below

```
 onsubmit="return md5hash(vb_login_password, vb_login_md5password, vb_login_md5password_utf, 0)"
```

And define `md5hash` into `Javascript` with `ture/false` value

Comment: Would you please provide with a java code example. What kind of object should be defined? get element by what?